# Why doesn't this SQL statement work

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I have two tables. Job and Location. I then want to query the database to get jobs that are in a certain location. Here are my database tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `contact_telephone` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `salary_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tenure_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `occupation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `img_url` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `region` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Why doesn't this query create an inner join between job and location?

```
SELECT * FROM job, location 
WHERE location.region = 'Central Coast' 
OR location.region = 'Hunter Valley' 
OR location.region = 'Illawarra' 
AND job.location_id = location.id
```

Comment: Don't mix ands and ors like that and consider moving to explicit joins.

Comment: Its good practice to use brackets when using AND OR statements. For more details look at his documents. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Tip2:  `... WHERE location.region IN ('Central Coast', 'Hunter Valley', 'llawarra') AND job.location_id = location.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `and` has a [higher precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) than `or`.

This means your `where` clause is executed as:

```
WHERE  location.region = 'Central Coast' 
       OR location.region = 'Hunter Valley' 
       OR (location.region = 'Illawarra' AND job.location_id = location.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax, as it is easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

And use `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM job
JOIN location ON job.location_id = location.id
WHERE location.region IN ('Central Coast', 'Hunter Valley', 'llawarra')
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland, no big deal. And Andomar pointed out the AND/OR precedence issue, which make sense!